# How can i get the full url in a Nuxt plugin?

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm having trouble accessing the url in my nuxt js plugin that has all. In short: there is a part in the url that shows me what country people are visiting from and that country should be used in the api calls.

`window.location`
doesn't work because it's SSR and window isn't available there.

`req.headers.host` doesn't work because nuxt generate has been run on the staging/production

Edit: The route object won't give me any info on the domain. Only parts after that. For example with [www.test.nl/about](http://www.test.nl/about) it will not return [www.test.nl](http://www.test.nl) anywhere

Is there a way i could get the full url in this scenario?

Comment: There is a $route or $router (or without the $ sign) object in context: export default function ({ $route }) {...}

Comment: The route object doesn't return the domain anywhere so i can't use that either

Comment: What about req.hostname?

Answer (score 1):

If it's really about the `host`, you can wrap your plugin code with a `process.client` check. This way your code only gets executed on the client and you can safely use `window.location.host`.

If the current route without the host is enough, you can use the `route` object, which is part of the context object which gets passed to your plugin (Works on server and client).

```js
export default function ({ route }) {
  if (process.client) {
    console.log(window.location.host)
  }

  console.log(route)
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i need the domain name and the rout object only gives info after that. For example with www.test.nl/about i would need to access the www.test.nl part and route will only give me /about

Comment: Then I would go for the `process.client` check and use the `window.location` object. That should fit your need, does it?

Comment: that doesn't trigger because it's all ssr to render a page

Comment: So what target did you define in your nuxt-config and should the code run on client, server or both?